# Use of Unresolved Identifier "Singleton."

Tags: swift, singleton

I'm coding an app involving singletons and I'm trying to access the singleton file from other files in my app. Here's my code:

Singleton.swift

```
class Singleton {
static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

private init() {
    // Private initialization to ensure just one instance is created.
}

}
```

OutofQuestionsVC.swift

```
class OutofQuestionsVC: UIViewController {
let mysingleton = Singleton.sharedInstance


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   mysingleton.resetQuestions()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

}
```

Comment: Do `Singleton.swift` and `OutofQuestionsVC.swift`  reside in different modules?

Comment: The `OutofQuestionsVC.swift` file resides in UIKit and `Singleton.swift` is in Foundation.

Comment: Both UIKit and Foundation are *Apple's* frameworks, not your code. Press `Cmd + Opt + 1` and check the `Target Membership` of each file.

Comment: Oh! The singleton was not included in the same target as the view controller. That's probably what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Design-Patterns-In-Swift project on github has an example

https://github.com/ochococo/Design-Patterns-In-Swift/blob/master/source/creational/singleton.swift

Example:

```
class DeathStarSuperlaser {
    static let sharedInstance = DeathStarSuperlaser()

    private init() {
        // Private initialization to ensure just one instance is created.
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 let laser = DeathStarSuperlaser.sharedInstance
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting your class you can do it this way:

```
class Singelton {
    class var sharedSingelton : Singelton {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : Singelton = Singelton()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

And for initializing (will be done automatically, if you access the singleton for the first time. Second time and so on the instance will be returned) you can do:

```
let singelton = Singelton.sharedSingelton
```

OR only

```
Singelton.sharedSingelton
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this problem has already been solved by Zoff Dino's comments.